# TreeAggregate In Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

How treeAggregate works for maximum, minimum functions?I have a two scenario in which one it works but in other not.

```
scala> val z = sc.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 2)
z: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:24


scala> z.treeAggregate(0)(
 | math.max(_, _), math.max(_, _)
 | )
res0: Int = 6


scala> z.treeAggregate(0)(
     |       seqOp = (U, v) => {
     |         math.max(U, v)
     |         U
     |       },
     |       combOp = (U1, U2) => {
     |         math.max(U1, U2)
     |         U1
     |       })
res1: Int = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Result of expression

```
{
   math.max(U, v)
   U
}
```

is `U`, so whole your second construction is basically selecting leftmost element of `RDD`, change your code to

```
z.treeAggregate(0)(
 seqOp = (u, v) => {
   math.max(u, v)
 },
 combOp = (u1, u2) => {
    math.max(u1, u2)
 })
```

to make it work similar to the first aggregation expression